# WP7 / WP8 - Apply text styles

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, textblock

As you know, in Windows Phone SDK there are several styles that you can apply to textblocks.
For reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_TextStyles)

Since you can't always remember the full name of the style, is there an easy way to apply them? Do I really have to go to that link everytime I need to apply a new style?

Comment: Blend has a menu that shows the resources you can apply on an element

Answer (score 0):

IntelliSense is not helpful enough? I usually, write `StaticResource text` and then the list gets filtered with all the styles containing the "text" string. Kind of depends according to your needs. If you want to apply for font style, write "font" and see the list of suggestions.

Now, I'm not sure if my IntelliSense is as yours or is already enhanced by Resharper. If you haven't heard of it, take a look at it. You gotta hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> if the suggestion list isn't there, and it will get filled with possible matches. It's a nice productivity tool that does **MUCH** more and actually is not free but, I guess you could also get it crac... ahem **:)**

Other than this, I guess a quick bookmark to that web address, does that job pretty well. **:)**

Comment: I wasn't specific enough; It does in XAML.

Comment: I can ensure you nothing is being displayed on keys press

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ensure you have the visual designer open while creating the view. You can right click on your TextBlock select Edit Style -> Apply Resource ->. From here you will see a long list of available styles to pick from.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that what I was looking for will be implemented in Visual Studio 2013!

Here you go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/09/xaml-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx